How to configure Azure Maps Creator manifest.json 2.0 to support wayfinding?
I'm attempting to get wayfinding working using the latest Azure Maps Creator 2023-03-01-preview APIs and lacking some know-how for how to supply the correct data for the package to support it.
The docs say wayfinding requires facility ontology 2.0 feature classes for "structure" and "verticalPenetration" in order to determine best path.  I presume I define these classes in the manifest.json v2 file.  However, the building package requirement docs for manifest 2.0 describes featureClassProperties as something that only maps to dwg layers, so I cannot for example specify if a "unit" isRouteable=true.
I've been using the v2 sample from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/am-creator-indoor-data-examples and modified the class names to match facility ontology 2.0 names for structure and verticalPenetration but for some reason the conversion service still interprets the data as a "custom" ontology.
How can the sample v2 package be modified to support wayfinding using this preview?
Edit:
So it appears that manifest.json 2.0 does not use ontology 2.0 feature classes when it comes to wayfinding.  Here's an example of wayfinding using the v2 sample.
I think the docs could do with clearing up this confusion?

Edit 2:
Here's another example, this time a path from level 0 to level 1 that uses the stair (str2) as a transition between levels.  Whilst the level transition is fine, the path clearly passes through walls between some way points, notably around another set of stairs str1, and rooms 1045 and 1341.  The changes of direction are also a bit janky if drawn using a polyline.  Are these expected behaviours from the routing engine behind the API?


Have you created a route set as per this document? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-creator-wayfinding

I have, but didn't try the routing api yet.  Are you implying that if I do use ontology 2.0 feature classes then routing should work?  If so, how do I specify properties like isRouteable?

I wonder if the docs are just confusing me.  On one hand they say class names "wall", "stair" and "elevator" should be used for wayfinding to work, but then links to Indoor maps concepts page describing the use of ontology 2.0 names.  I'll try drawing a generated path to confirm if walls are avoided using the original v2 sample.

I can confirm that I the wayfinding api does avoid "wall" as used in the vs sample package.  This would imply ontology 2.0 is not used.  The docs make this somewhat confusing.  I'll add an image of the resulting wayfind path to the question.

My 2nd edit diagram which shows walls and stairs path overlap issues is mostly due to me stupidly only showing the one ground floor image.  When the upper floor is visible for the 2nd path leg then there is only one overlap (room 1341).  So overlap still occurs but nowhere near as bad as shown.
